# DOMDocument getElementsByTagName not working

Tags: php, xml-parsing, domdocument

I'm trying to use the `DOMDocument` function `getElementsByTagName()`, but it keeps returning an empty object. I'm using the following code:

```
// Create some HTML
$output = '
<html>
   <body>
      <a href="foo">Bar</a>
   </body>
</html>';

// Load the HTML
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($output);

// Find all links (a tags)
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

var_dump($links); // object(DOMNodeList)#31 (0) { } - empty object
```

What am I missing? Looking at the documentation, it looks like I'm using the function correctly.

Comment: $dom is in fact your HTML document? You are sure that the 'error' occurs at the getElementsByTagName and not before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That `var_dump` is just saying that you have a `DOMNodeList` object. Traverse the list and you'll see it's there:

```
foreach( $links as $a) {
     echo $a->nodeName . ' ' . $a->nodeValue;
}
```

This would output:

```
a Bar
```

Since it's an `<a>` tag, and its contents are `Bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are expecting out of the `var_dump`, but the element is included in that nodelist as you can see:

```
var_dump($links->item(0));
//object(DOMElement)#3 (0) {}
var_dump($links->item(0)->getAttribute("href"));
//string(3) "foo"
```